# Pass data to post.php in the background form fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

I have this script that works well for sending a message from a form via post. But I would like to add more information from the form to be sent via the script but can't get it working?! Do I have to have have one  $.post("post.php" .. for every input? Thanks a million.

```
    --- THIS ONE IS SENT FINE TO post.php --
<input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" />

    --- WOULD LIKE TO ADD THESE TO THE SCRIPT --
<input type="hidden" name="request" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="sentby" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="sentto" value="3" />

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submitmsg").click(function () {
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        $.post("post.php", { text: clientmsg });
        $("#usermsg").val("");
        return false;
       });
});
```

Comment: you want to send more data via post? you can send more data by including that data in your json like: $.post("post.php", { text: clientmsg, sentby: $("input[name=sentby]").val(), ....   });

Comment: ok, thanks. So I have to have $.post("post.php", { text: clientmsg, sentby: $("input[name=sentby]").val(), .... }); per input.. and then finish with just one return false in the end?

Comment: no, its a json file, there is no return into it

Comment: ok, thanks.. so all this is what should be repeated for every input "var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        $.post("post.php", { text: clientmsg });
        $("#usermsg").val("");"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submitmsg").click(function () {
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        var request = $("#request").val();
        var sentby = $("#sentby").val();
        var sentto = $("#sentto").val();    
        $.post("post.php", 
              { 
                 text: clientmsg,
                 request: request,
                 sentby: sentby,
                 sentto: sentto,
              },
              function(result){
                  // you can do anything you want with result
              });
        $("#usermsg").val("");
        return false;
       });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much Behzad. I appreciate it.  I'm trying to get it working but I have some kind of problem with the post.php inserting the values.  I'll get back to you shortly!

Comment: It's strange, but the only one getting data in the post.php is the first one   ($text = $_POST['text'];) .... None of the others are getting data in ($requestid = $_POST['request'];  $sentby = $_POST['sentby']; and so on.. )

Comment: Thanks again, found my problem. I had forgotten to put id="x" in the form fields!! Now it works!